# Problem with circuit cam, can't view my top layer?

Tags: pcb, orcad, allegro

I have a circuit laid out in allegro and I'll be milling it out on a board router. I'm using Circuit Cam to produce the files needed for the board router. I have three layers, a top layer, a bottom layer, and a mech layer. I also have a drill file. When I import my files, everything looks fine except for the top layer, which has all of my routed traces. When I view the top layer all I see is a big white rectangle. I will post some pictures in a couple hours. But has anyone used circuit cam before and had this problem?

The first image shows my allegro layout. I opened up the film control to show that the TOP layer has VIA CLASS/TOP, PIN/TOP, AND ETCH/TOP. When I import this to circuitCAM, however, I get the white rectangle on the second image. 
[image]

Comment: Try this http://www.graphicode.com/ see what is says, it's free.  You could post a link to that layer if you want and I'll load it on my system and tell you what I see.

Comment: You might also go into Allegro and see what layers you have turned on for the top layer gerber generation

Comment: In allegro I have via class/top, pin/top, and etch/top. These are the ones that I want for the top layer.

Answer (score 1):

Had some file issues. Got them fixed. In the second image above there was one last step where I had to press OK. It appeared as a big white rectangle because I was importing in an old copy of the file where my traces were really narrow and the image above is a zoomed out version so it just appeared as a white rectangle. After pressing OK, it went to a different mode where everything worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some details on what the issues were? Otherwise the answer doesn't seem too useful for anyone else.

Comment: Well, its actually pretty embarrassing. In the second image above there was one last step where I had to press OK. It appeared as a big white rectangle because I was importing in an old copy of the file where my traces were really narrow and the image above is a zoomed out version so it just appeared as a white rectangle. After pressing OK, it went to a different mode where everything worked fine.